# Is my explanation for this function correct?

Tags: calculus

I have wrote an explanation to problem B, which states at which points is the not differentiable. I was wondering if my explanation was correct. Should I add or remove anything? Thanks.

[image]

Explanation: A function is not differentiable under 3 conditions. The first case is when the function has a vertical tangent line. The second case is when the function is not continuous. The third case is when the function has a sharp turn, because as it approaches the point or value both lines are heading towards on either side, the slopes are different. This also results in the limit not existing since the values are different on the left and right hand sides. In this function, you can see that there are no discontinuities nor has a vertical tangent line listed. But, the function does have sharp turns at the x values of 0, 1, and 4 because the slope of the lines change during those intervals. The first line has a slope of 1/2, the second has -4, the third has zero, and the fourth has 2, which makes the function not differentiable at those 3 points since the slopes are different.

Comment: Depending on the definition of differentiability you are using, you might have to consider $x=-4$ and $x=6$ as well. Unless "between" means strictly in between.